# GORM: how to retrieve only two values for dropdown

Tags: grails, drop-down-menu, grails-orm

In Grails using GORM, I'd like to retrieve two possible values for a form dropdown.  This particular instance is to only have two possible countries in a dropdown.  I've set them in my Config.groovy

The GORM statement in this that I've done only returns USA and I'd like to return Canada also - so I have the findAll statement slightly incorrect.  Can someone help me?

```
Country<g:select name="Country"  from="${....country.findAllById("100225","100038").sort{it.orderNumber}}" value="otherstuff" class="form-control" required="" aria-labelledby="country-label"/>
```

Config.groovy:

```
country.usa=100225
country.canada=100038
```

Domain class:

```
class country {

    String name
    String value
    int orderNumber = 0

    static constraints = {
        name nullable:false, maxSize:50, blank:false
        value nullable:false, maxSize:100, blank:false
    }

    String toString(){
        "$name - $value"
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'country'
        cache: 'read-write'
        columns{
            id column:'id'
            name column:'name'
            value column:'value'
            orderNumber column:'order_number'
        }
        id generator: 'assigned'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should rather use `findAllByIdInList(["100225","100038"])`.

Also consider not writing such code within the view.  Make it part of your model and prepare it in the controller.

Comment: what do you mean by the (yourWhiteList) part?  I confess I haven't see that before.  And also, what would be an alternate way to do it in the controller?

Comment: the list of ids, you want to get the objects for.  something like `["100225","100038"]`

Comment: where do I make the list?

Comment: i have changed the answer to eliminate all doubts.  and you should do it in the controller (like all other code to setup your model).

Comment: thanks so much.  I'm actually new to Grails, so I'm sorry if I sounded ignorant.  I will try to practice it both ways.   many thanks.